# Swap to ASP.NET membership provider from Simple membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an existing system written in MVC4 that uses the SimpleMembershipProvider.  It was initialised using the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` method.

We have a need to integrate "Yet Another Forum" into our system using a single signon approach.  We managed to get this to work but now we are encountering errors, specifically the below error with the ApplicationName() method not supported.

```
[NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.get_ApplicationName() +57
   System.Web.Security.Membership.get_ApplicationName() +17
   YAF.Classes.YafBoardSettings..ctor() +190
   YAF.Core.YafLoadBoardSettings..ctor(Int32 boardID) +34
   YAF.Core.CurrentBoardSettings.<get_Instance>b__0() +81
   YAF.Core.HttpApplicationStateBaseExtensions.GetOrSet(HttpApplicationStateBase httpApplicationState, String key, Func`1 getValue) +311
   YAF.Core.CurrentBoardSettings.get_Instance() +122
   YAF.Core.Modules.ServicesModule.<RegisterServices>b__3(IComponentContext k) +81
   Autofac.<>c__DisplayClass10`1.<Register>b__f(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +10
   Autofac.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +14
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +44

[DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Specified method is not supported. (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +112
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +109
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +74
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) +68
   YAF.Core.AutoFacServiceLocatorProvider.Get(Type serviceType) +81
   YAF.Types.Interfaces.IServiceLocatorExtensions.Get(IServiceLocator serviceLocator) +142
   YAF.Types.Interfaces.IServiceLocatorExtensions.Get(IHaveServiceLocator haveLocator) +131
   YAF.Core.YafContext.get_BoardSettings() +46
   YAF.Core.UnloadSessionForumModule.UnloadSessionModule_Unload(Object sender, EventArgs e) +120
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnUnload(EventArgs e) +9583810
   YAF.Forum.OnUnload(EventArgs e) +7
   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +227
   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +163
   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +163
   System.Web.UI.Page.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +23
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestCleanup() +56
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.yaf_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +4
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

According to Microsoft's documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.applicationname(v=vs.111).aspx, if you use this method then the ApplicationName property isn't available.

Is it possible to use the SimpleMembershipProvider in the "other" mode, or migrate to the ASP.NET membership provider yet retain our existing users in the system?

Comment: Well, there is no single membership provider.  There are quite a few.  The issue is that you need a provider that implements enough of the API to make Yaf happy.  Unfortunately, the table structure, and hashing algorithms are different for SimpleMembership vs SqlMembership and many others..

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We wound up using a different method entirely, which resolved our issue.